# Cannot create Store in redux with thunk middlewear

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm having issues with creating my store using redux. I have a feeling it is how my createStore is passing in the middleware.

The line `return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk), initialState)' is giving me the warning Argument Type GenericStoreEnhancer is not assignable to parameter type StoreEnhancer`

What does that mean?

I believe I'm following the documentation [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/applyMiddleware.md) correctly, so I'm at a loss.

I know my store is not being created/exported correctly because I'm getting an undefined for my state.

Any ideas how to create the store correctly?

Thanks,

Here is my `configureStore.js` file:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

    export default function configureStore(initialState) {

    return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk), initialState);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify your initial state in each `reducer` and **not** by `createStore`.

For example,

```js
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

docs:
https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: Actually, the OP is doing it right according to Redux docs https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state

Answer (score 0):

> **return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk), initialState)' is giving me the warning Argument Type GenericStoreEnhancer is not assignable to parameter type StoreEnhancer**

Its because ,you are passing parameter in wrong order to [`creatStore`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md)

The right signature is,

**[createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html)**

Please refer [`redux-docs`](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html)

So,it should be like this.

```
createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this! Even after changing the order to `rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk)` I'm still getting the same error?

Comment: @Mirko If it possible,please provide codesandbox for react.It will easy to work on this issue